# Call Grunt task from subdirectory

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I'm struggling with how to make this work. I have a casper test in which I need to run a Grunttask at the end of. The problem is the directory structure which I've added below.

package.json

Gruntfile.js

casperjs/

--- web/

------ tests/

--------- test.js

And in test.js I'm calling grunt.task.run(['mytestname']);
When I run the casper test I get **"uncaughtError: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: grunt"**.

Any ideas? Thanks!

**UPDATE**

In the testfile I've added var grunt = require('../../../../Gruntfile.js'); but then I get an error saying grunt.task.run is undefined. Think I'm heading in the right direction.

Comment: From what I'm reading, you should have a `Gruntfile.js` in your `tests` folder with a `mytestname` task - otherwise are you sure casperjs should be in charge to launch the task ?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. It's a pretty unique test so Casper does need to launch this task but generally I'd agree with you. I don't want to create a seperate Gruntfile if possible is my main issue because this is a one test in a pretty large suite we've developed. I'm looking for a way to import that grunt file into my test file.

Comment: I don't understand how you're ever calling that JS file. Can you tell us how that code is run? Also, seeing your grunt config for the casper test task may prove helpful.